# Replace null value by empty in map in flutter?

Tags: sql-server, list, flutter, dart, null

I am a beginner in flutter and in first project of mine I try to retrieve value to textfields in personal profile of app. This is my code line that get values from a public list named Info_user_list that works but placed null, how can I remove null value and replace it by ' ' in these lines? Are there any other methods to do that?

```
 name_profile_controller.text=(info_user_list.map((e) => e.name).toList().join(""));


email_profile_controller.text=info_user_list.map((e) => e!=null ? e.username : ' ').toList().join("");
```

This lines for null-values placed null (as A word) and for non-null placed right values, problem just belongs to null values.

Comment: Is the problem that `e` is `null` or `e.username` / `e.name` is `null`?

Comment: e.name was null in data base and it printed NULL in app's textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    name_profile_controller.text = info_user_list.map((e) => e.name ?? "").toList().join(" ");
    email_profile_controller.text = info_user_list.map((e) => e.username ?? "").toList().join(" ");
```